# обратный отсчёт с нулями

Tags: javascript

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

var total_items = 50;
var d = new Date();
var min_items_left = 8;
var max_items_left = 12;

let counterItems = null;

if (false && sessionStorage) {
    counterItems = sessionStorage.getItem(StorageKeys.counterItems);
}

var remaining_items = counterItems ? Number(counterItems) : randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left, max_items_left);

var min_of_remaining_items = 3;
var decrease_after = 1.7;
var decrease_after_first_item = 0.17;

jQuery.noConflict()(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // $("#progress_bar").progressbar();
        // var tag = "ctdn-12-12".match(/\d+/g);
        var hour = 14;
        var theDaysBox = $("#numdays");
        var theHoursBox = $("#numhours");
        var theMinsBox = $("#nummins");
        var theSecsBox = $("#numsecs");
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getDay();
        var date = 7;
        var gg = 14;
        var hh = 12;
        var ii = 30;
        var nsec = 0 - d.getSeconds();
        if (nsec < 0) {
            nsec = 60 - d.getSeconds();
            gg = 1
        }
        var nmin = 0 - d.getMinutes() - gg;
        if (nmin < 0) {
            nmin = 60 - d.getMinutes() - gg;
            hh = 1
        }
        var nhrs = 14 - d.getHours() - hh;
        if (nhrs < 0) {
            nhrs = 38 - d.getHours() - hh;
            ii = 1
        }
        var ndat = date - 1;
        if (ndat < 0) {
            var mmon = d.getMonth();
            ndat = 30 + date - d.getDate() - ii
        }

        let counterData = null;

        if (false && sessionStorage) {
            counterData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(StorageKeys.counter));
        }

        // use the stored valued value if present
        theSecsBox.html(counterData ? counterData.nsec : nsec);
        theMinsBox.html(counterData ? counterData.nmin : nmin);
        theHoursBox.html(counterData ? counterData.nhrs : nhrs);
        theDaysBox.html(counterData ? counterData.ndat : ndat);

        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            var e = theSecsBox.text();
            var a = theMinsBox.text();
            var c = theHoursBox.text();
            var b = theDaysBox.text();

            if (false && sessionStorage) {
                const currentValues = { nsec: e, nmin : a, nhrs : c, ndat : b };
                sessionStorage.setItem(StorageKeys.counter, JSON.stringify(currentValues));
            }

            if (e == 0 && a == 0 && c == 0 && b == 0) {}
            else {
                if (e == 0 && a == 0 && c == 0) {
                    theDaysBox.html(b - 1);
                    theHoursBox.html("23");
                    theMinsBox.html("59");
                    theSecsBox.html("59")
                }
                else {
                    if (e == 0 && a == 0) {
                        theHoursBox.html(c - 1);
                        theMinsBox.html("59");
                        theSecsBox.html("59")
                    }
                    else {
                        if (e == 0) {
                            theMinsBox.html(a - 1);
                            theSecsBox.html("59")
                        }
                        else {
                            theSecsBox.html(e - 1)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

На данный момент нуля отсеиваются, нужно что бы нули остались, например 06 дней, 07 часов, 02 минуты, 08 секунд

Comment: так выводите соответственно `x >= 10 ? x : '0' + x`

Comment: а по подробнее ? я не силён в синтакисе js

Comment: разобрался, ну так он просто прибавляет 0, то есть не сам отсчёт

Comment: Предоставьте пожалуйста так же `html` код, чтобы можно без проблем запустить у себя. А если умеете, то создайте сниппет, но если нет мы отредактируем

Answer (score 0):

Вообще лучше работать через переменные, а не через `text()` элементов.

Вот пример измененного кода:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    if (false && sessionStorage) {
        const currentValues = { nsec: nsec, nmin : nmin, nhrs : nhrs, ndat : ndat };
        sessionStorage.setItem(StorageKeys.counter, JSON.stringify(currentValues));
    }

    if (nsec == 0 && nmin == 0 && nhrs == 0 && ndat == 0) {}
    else {
        if (nsec == 0 && nmin == 0 && nhrs == 0) {
            ndat = ndat - 1;
            nhrs = 23;
            nmin = 59;
            nsec = 59;
        }
        else {
            if (nsec == 0 && nmin == 0) {
                nhrs = nhrs - 1;
                nmin = 59;
                nsec = 59;
            }
            else {
                if (nsec == 0) {
                    nmin = nmin - 1;
                    nsec = 59;
                }
                else {
                    nsec = nsec - 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    theDaysBox.html(ndat >= 10 ? ndat : '0' + ndat);
    theHoursBox.html(nhrs >= 10 ? nhrs : '0' + nhrs);
    theMinsBox.html(nmin >= 10 ? nmin : '0' + nmin);
    theSecsBox.html(nsec >= 10 ? nsec : '0' + nsec);
}, 1000);
```